# loopback error - callback was already called

Tags: loopbackjs

I am using a observer on loopback model to store the model data in before save event. However i am getting error ,

**(node:10760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Callback was already called**

Following is implementation of callback

```
 async function eventSelObserver(ctx, next) {
        console.log("eventSelObserver");
        if ( ! (ctx.isNewInstance) && ctx.currentInstance) {
            ctx.hookState.SelhistoryData = [ctx.currentInstance.toObject()];
        }
        console.log("before calling next");
        return next();
    }
```

Following is the way used to register the callback

```
 obsModels.observe("before save", eventSelObserver);
```

Here the callback inside the eventSelObserver is called only once.
Any pointers for the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the way you're handling asynchronicity, if you were to use async/await syntax then you don't need to pass `next`. Also, you need to await the value you're assigning.

```js
async function eventSelObserver(ctx) {
  console.log('eventSelObserver');
  if (!ctx.isNewInstance && ctx.currentInstance) {
    ctx.hookState.SelhistoryData = await ctx.currentInstance.toObject();
  }
  return;
}

obsModels.observe('before save', await eventSelObserver);
```

Ref: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#using-asyncawait